# Entity Framework 5 ntext equals error

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, ntext

i have the following error when trying to find a record in database by `ntext` field using `Entity Framework`

```
enter code hereThe data types ntext and nvarchar are incompatible 
in the equal to operator.
```

I found a few articles here related to that issue but i can't modify database and change column type.

Comment: Show us your query or the generated query by EF ?

Comment: @CodeNotFound elementary `dbContext.Collection.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Field = "value")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve that problem using `dbcontext.database.sqlquery` with `like` operator to compare `ntext` rows with my value.